# jquery-ui, autocomplite

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Как реализовать с помощью *autocomplite* такую штуку? Нужно сделать выпадающее меню, в котором есть массив городов, если пользователь ввел некорректное название города, выводится пункт "Моего города нету в списке".
Пока он вводит данные, этот элемент тоже нужно показывать.

Пример:
**В html есть input  при редактировании input-a,он заполняется подсказками для ввода с jquery через autocomplete.**

**html code**

```
<input type="text" class="city" id="city" list="city-arr" placeholder="Город проживания">
```

**jquery code**

```
$(function(){
    cityArr = [
        "Киев",
        "Харьков",
        "Моего города нету в списке"
    ];
    $("#city").autocomplete({
        source:cityArr
    });
});
```

Comment: Что именно у вас не получилось?

Comment: @tutankhamun именно не получается все время выводить элемент списка с значением "Моего значения нету в списке". Тоесть если у меня есть массив с элементами "аaa" и "bbb". Я ввожу "а", показывает элемент "ааа" для его выбора, но также всегда должен последним выводиться "Мое значения нет в списке". Когда введу к примеру что то, что не попадает под выборку в массиве, к примеру "ррр" то выведется только один элемент "Моего знач. нету в списке". Он нужен для того что бы при его выборе появилось новое доп. поле для ввода.

Comment: добавьте пример, как вы используете _autocomplite_, как настраиваете, и передаете данные

Comment: @Grundy Не видел комментария. Добавил пример использования

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае нужно передавать функцию в поле *source*.

Функция принимает два параметра:

1. Объект с полем terms - в котором хранится введенное значение
2. функция, которую нужно вызвать и передать ей отфильтрованные значения. Так что основное отличие от того, что есть сейчас - фильтровать придется вручную. Но зато это позволит добавить необходимые элементы.

Например вот так:

```js
$(function(){
    cityArr = [
        "Киев",
        "Харьков"
    ];
    $("#city").autocomplete({
        source:function(request, response){
          
          response(cityArr.filter(function(el){return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase()) > -1; }).concat("Моего города нету в списке"));
          }
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="city" id="city" list="city-arr" placeholder="Город проживания">
```